# Use of int function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is working fine but I am confused why I only have to change `age` into an integer and not `months`, `weeks` or `days`. If I simply add `age = 25`, then it does not give any error.

```
age = input("What is your current age? ")

Years_remaining = Years_remaining = (90 - int(age))
months = Years_remaining * 12
weeks =  Years_remaining * 52
days =  Years_remaining * 365

print (f"you have {days} days, {weeks} weeks, and {months} months left")
```

Comment: `input` always returns a string, if you want to work with it as a number you have to convert it.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks for clearing my doubt

Comment: @Himanshu - Here is a link to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) as it shows the return value of `input` is always a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why:
`age` is `str` as this is what the `input` method returns, therefore, you have to cast to `int` to subtract it to 90 and store it in `Years_remaining`.

At this point, `Years_remaining` is an `int`, so `months` does not need any cast as both of its operands are now `int` (Years_remaining and 12).

If for example, you would cast `age` to `float`, then `months`, `weeks`, etc would be a `float` as well.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Got it , so when ever I am using Input , it will by default return a string and if I want to perform any math operation I need to convert it to int

Comment: yes, to `int` or any other built-int type or class, it depends on what you are doing next with this data